# Iterating over rows in a Dataframe to generate a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, iterator

I am trying to create a new column called 'delayed_or_not' by iterating over the rows to assign 'delayed' when the 'Shipment_day_Scheduled' column is less than the 'Order_to_shipment_day' column and assign 'not delayed' if otherwise. However, only my if statement is running thereby assigning delayed to all the rows even when the condition is not met.[image]

I tried using an if and else statement embedded in a for loop. I was expecting for example; the column 'delayed_or_not' to be 'Not delayed' in the second row but i got 'delayed'

Comment: please provide your data and code in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples): **text**, not images.

Comment: You need to use `shift`, never use `iterrows` in pandas